# Get width/height of SCNText Geometry

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm looking for a possibility to calculate the size of an SCNText Geometry. I want to make a row of individual text nodes that have a frame around the text.

Let's say the text has 5pt width. I want a SCNPlane as background with a width of 7pt and the text centred inside. How can I calculate the text size dynamically? I tried different things.. Monospace Fonts, counting bigger and smaller chars etc. But it didn't work out.

Like this:

```
----------  ----------
|  Text  |  |  Text  |
----------  ----------
```

Here some sample code:

```
let textGeometry = SCNText(string: name, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
textGeometry.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 1)
let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeometry);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SCNNode` and `SCNGeometry` (and thus `SCNText`) conform to the `SCNBoundingVolume` protocol. The method your are looking for is `-getBoundingBoxMin:max:`

Comment: In Swift 3.0, it's .boundingBox.  e.g.  geometry.boundingBox.min.y

Comment: what the same meathod in objc?